# Utility method to read JSON data from a URL

Tags: java

I am reading JSON data from two URLs, and parsing them using google GSON into two of my custom java objects. I need help coming up with a static method to do the JSON to Java parsing using Gson. Ideally if it was a single return type, I would have managed to come up with the method myself, but since the return type will be two different objects, I am unable to figure it out. Any tips to get a head start will be great.

Comment: Return an `Object[]` or call two different methods.

Comment: I want to have a single method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following method for read both urls.

```
   public static <T> T fromJsonToJava(String jsonUrl, Class<T> type) throws IOException {
      URL url = new URL(jsonUrl);
      URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
      InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();         
      Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
      Gson gson = new Gson();
      return gson.fromJson(reader, type);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use org.json Library: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20090211

Sample JSON from Http Response:

```
{ "key":"value" }
```

Code to get the `value` of `key`:

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;

HttpGet http = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(http);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

// To parse the JSON response
// EntityUtils.toString(entity) is { "key":"value" }
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
String value = jsonObject.getString("key");
```

Comment: Sorry that's not what I am looking for. I already have the code in place to do the parsing. Like I mentioned I just need a static method that takes in the two URLs as input, and returns objects of different types based on what data is contained in the URL. The reason being, in future, we could have more URLs, and multiple return types. So I just need a utility method. That's it.